# How do I change the output path for local EAS builds in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

How can i change the path of EAS local builds?

Currently when i run a local EAS build, the build output is in the project root. I would like to define a custom path for the build output.

I have tried reading through the docs and the most promising is https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/eas-json/. But it is still not 100% clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the `--output` flag.

Example - `eas build -p ios --local --profile production --output "<CUSTOM_DIRECTORY>/<ipa|aab>"`

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**
Using a couple of env variables you can set it as below. This is from the [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/#using-local-builds-for-debugging):

`EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_WORKINGDIR` - Specify the working directory for the build process, by default it's somewhere (it's platform dependent) in /tmp folder.

`EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_SKIP_CLEANUP=1` - Set this to disable cleaning up the working directory after the build process is finished.

**Method 2.**
It is mentioned in the `--help` that it can be done by adding the `--output` flag after the `--local` and specifying the output directory as below (showing other flags too).

```
eas build [-p android|ios|all] [-e <value>] [--local] [--output <value>] [--wait] [--clear-cache]
    [--auto-submit | --auto-submit-with-profile <value>] [-m <value>] [--json --non-interactive]
```

**Note:**
Method 1 takes precedence over Method 2, meaning if you set the env variable, Method 2 does not work.

Comment: For some reason, Method 2 is no longer for me.